# Return deferred object for return value Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, promise, dojo, jasmine

I am trying to fake a return of a deferred object in jasmine, for an Angular2 component I am testing.

Component function:

```
 public createAndExecuteIdentify(url) {
      identifyTask = this._widgetFactory.createIdentifyTask(url); //returns object
      return identifyTask.execute(this.identifyParams);  //this returns a deferred  
 }
```

Spec:

```
 let fakeTask: any;

 fakeTask = {
        execute: jasmine.createSpy('execute'),
        url: "bob@bob.com"
 };
 fakeFactory.createIdentifyTask.and.returnValue(fakeIdentifyTask);

 describe("when executing identifyTask", () => {
    it("should return the proper object", () => {
        let taskReturn = component.createAndExecuteIdentify(fakeTask.url);
        expect(taskReturn).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
            promise: {}
        }));
    });
});
```

This works great, other than the fact that fakeTask.execute does not return deferred.

The desired result of fakeTask.execute() would return an object like this:

```
 b.Deferred {promise: {…}, isResolved: ƒ, isRejected: ƒ, isFulfilled: ƒ, 
 isCanceled: ƒ, …}
 addCallbacks: ƒ (a,b)
 callback: ƒ (a)
 cancel: ƒ ()
 errback: ƒ (a)
 isCanceled: ƒ ()
 isFulfilled: ƒ ()
 isRejected: ƒ ()
 isResolved: ƒ ()
 progress: ƒ (a)
 promise: {isResolved: ƒ, isRejected: ƒ, isFulfilled: ƒ, isCanceled: ƒ, then: ƒ, …}
 reject: ƒ (a)
 resolve:ƒ (a) then: ƒ (b,d,h)
 _pendingDfd: b.Deferred {promise: {…}, isResolved: ƒ, isRejected: ƒ, isFulfilled: ƒ, isCanceled: ƒ, …}
 __proto__: Object
```

So I am wondering if somehow setting up the fakeTask's execute spy to return deferred would work? (The real thing returns a Deferred Dojo type as shown above.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/Deferred.html)

Comment: `fakeTask.execute.and.returnValue(...)`? Note that your example seems to use inconsistent names, so isn't a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, it is part of a more complex component, and a little tricky to break out. Angular's $q library seemed interesting, but not sure if there is an equivalent for Angular2?

Comment: 'fakeTask.execute.and.returnValue(...)' almost works. It gives me the object I need, but it does affect the object type. So I get the error:

**TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.**

In my real exampe, the object type is listed as b.Deferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

```
 import Deferred from "dojo/Deferred";

 let deferred = new Deferred();
 fakeTask.execute.and.returnValue(deferred);
```

This makes the object type recognizable to a type of deferred.